# Is the default configuration good in Jetty 8 sensible for quite heavily loaded web application?

Tags: java, performance, jetty, default, jetty-8

Its been decided to deploy an application to Jetty 8, previously was using Tomcat 7. Jetty 8 is being used using the defaults, and seems to be working okay, but then occasionally waiting for connections, looking at the jetty.xml I'm confused about the interplay between threads and connectors.

But the general question is should the defaults work for a quite heavily loaded web application or are their obvious changes that need to be made ?

**Update**
Let me try and me more specific about this.

In jetty.xml it says maxThreads=200 so it can in theory deal with 200 requests in parallel (more than we have to deal with) , but is there a rule of thumb about how much memory jetty should be configured with to go with this.

It also defines a SelectChannelConnector connector, I assume this is the thing that receives requests and farms them out to threads. is this connector the best performing one available to us ?

Comment: Hey Paul! You need to be more specific I think. *How* heavily loaded and what does *work* mean, with *what* web application? Overall it feels like this is too vague a question unless you change it to 'What is a good configuration for performance in Jetty 8?'

Comment: hi Dan, okay rephrased slightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the defaults should be generally fine for what you describe.  A quick tweak you can make is to set the number of acceptors to the number of cpu's you have.  Aside from that you can always enable jmx and see how things look memory wise using jconsole to see something else might need to be tweaked.

We have some OS related things mentioned on this link as well:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/High_Load